# Unable to run C# method and avoid postback when I click on my ImageButton

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following ImageButton, which toggles the visibility property of a calendar control.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/calendar.png" OnClick="Display_Calendar1"/>
```

Problem is, when I click on it, it sends a postback command which conflicts with some of my other code. I've seen there are multiple threads about this where the most common solution is to call "return false;" on the OnClick event. However, I still need to run the calendar toggle method:

```
//cStart_Date is the calendar control and tbStart_Date is a textbox where I write down the chosen date.
protected void Display_Calendar1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)  
{
    if (IsValidDate(tbStart_Date.Text))
    {
        cStart_Date.SelectedDate = Convert2Date(tbStart_Date.Text);
        cStart_Date.VisibleDate = cStart_Date.SelectedDate;
    }
    cStart_Date.Visible = !cStart_Date.Visible;
}
```

In all the examples I've seen, the function ran before the "return false;" is a JavaScript function, but I want it to run my C# method. This results in a Server error when I launch it on the browser, displaying
**Compiler Error Message: CS1026:) expected**

I've also tried the method without arguments *protected void Display_Calendar1()* but the result is the same...

Comment: To run your C# method, you will have to send *something* to the server, because the C# method is running on the server. Can you clarify what the question is exactly? It seems you are a bit confused about how a web application runs and where it runs?

Comment: In short, I want that when I click on the ImageButton the calendar control becomes visible (with a selected date if the adjacent textbox has a valid date string). I want this to be done without triggering the Page_Load (IsPostback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay apparently **you cannot avoid the postback when execute the server side Click event**. An updatePanel will minimize the rendering load and minimize page flickering but there will still be a postback call, thus defeating my purpose. I guess doing it with javascript on the client side is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Toggling of calendar control can also be done through java script. You need to use OnClientClick property of Image button.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/calendar.png" OnClientClick="ToggleCalendar"/> 

<script>
function ToggleCalendar() {
    var clndr= document.getElementById('cStart_Date');
    clndr.style.display = (clndr.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
}
</script>
```

You can perform validation or other stuffs as well in Java script funtion.

Comment: I'm a complete newbie with javascript, I could manage to toggle the calendar control by elementid like you did, but I've no idea how to set its selectedDate, visibleDate, or use the dateconversion method I made to manage different datetime formats

Comment: Np.. :) Google your issue one by one you will get plenty of solutions. document.getElementById is the basic to reach to any control. Then you can access their properties.

Comment: I mean the point of my question was precisely to find out if there's another  way and avoid having to use javascript..

Comment: Hmm... The option I can see now is UpdatePanel. Place your controls inside an updatepanel. Check if it works.